# How to get access to environment variables in Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, path, environment-variables

I have borrowed a laptop with Windows XP from a company that I will do a project for. They say that I have almost Admiinistrator rights on the computer so that I can install software.

Now I have installed a few development tools, but I need to add a few things to the PATH environment variable. But I don't seem to have permissions to edit the PATH environment variable. Is there any way I could workaround this? Could I create a personal environment variable PATH that is used instead?

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/33681/how-can-i-modify-a-users-path-environment-variable-without-logging-out/33720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about whether your rights will allow it but you can try setting the path for a command window with `path = %PATH%;newdir`; if it works, it will last until the command window is closed. This may be ok for you if you are mostly working at the command line.

There is also the [setx](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) tool that you could try if your rights allow you to install it.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100102023818/http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm) is some additional information about the environment variables that may prove useful.

Comment: I tried this and tested `setx` but I got this message: `Access is denied`. I don't think it's possible to fix this. I have to contact the company. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The correct syntax in `cmd` shell is **`set path=%path%;newdir`** - note the `set` prefix and no whitespace around `=`

Comment: @grawity The `set` is deliberately missing. Jonas explained in the question that he wasn't allowed to use `set` to set the path. I wasn't sure where the block came in so I was pointing out a way to change the path for the current command window, with the hope that this might not be prevented by the lack of admin rights. I didn't bother listing the standard methods of changing the path *because I read the question which told me they didn't work*.

Comment: The question does not mention `set` anywhere. There's more than one way of editing environment; maybe Jonas was talking about the GUI. (Besides, it is _not possible_ to disable the `set` builtin except by patching `cmd.exe`, and even then there are many ways to get around it.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create your own environment.

- GUI:

  - System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

    - Or, if you don't have access this way, you might be able to get it by running `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` from the Run window or commandline.
  - Click *Add*, enter `PATH` as name and `%PATH%;mynewdir` as value. (You don't need to include `%PATH%` via the GUI, especially if you are editing an existing `PATH` variable; it just holds the string value of `PATH` before you made edits.)
  - This is the only method that ensures instant availability to all future processes launched by Explorer, without the need to re-login.
- Kinda GUI:

  - `regedit` -> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`
  - Right-click, *New* -> *Expandable String Value*
- CLI:

  - `reg add hkcu\environment /v PATH /t reg_expand_sz /d %%PATH%%;mynewdir`
  - Doubled `%%` is required to prevent `%%PATH%%` from being expanded by shell.